# R runs out of memory after only consuming ~200MB

Tags: r, memory-management, plot, out-of-memory

I have the following script:

```
mydata <- read.csv(file="priceData.txt", head=TRUE, sep='\t')    
plot(mydata$Date, mydata$Price)
```

mydata$Date and $Price are of length 98385. It seems to read the data fine, I can do computations on it no problem. I can build new vectors based on that data, but I can't plot against it.

If I try, I receive the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.1 Gb
>       In addition: Warning messages:
>       1: In rep.int(boxwex, n) :
>       Reached total allocation of 6135Mb: see help(memory.size)

This is bogus. It is using ~170MB on average when the crash occurs. I'm running Rgui with R-2.12.2 on 64bit Win7. And the total memory usage as reported by Task Manager is ~2GB for the whole system (out of 6GB I have).

I don't understand how I can be running out of memory.

Comment: changing plot command to "plot(mydata$Price)" plots it fine... so it's just the 2 axis that trip it up.

Comment: It's probably not that it's 2-axis but that one axis is a date object?  Try plotting price against price or something similar.  
Memory limits can be changed here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/memory.size.html
Did you do as it says and see help(memory.size)?

Comment: Can you report the output of `str(myData)`?

Comment: @gsk3: yes, it does appear to be date field. And I did follow those instructions and the max memory was already set to all my ram. So it seams that if Date and Time field is not in the format it expects, it doesn't tell you that, but instead goes into some weird state and throws OutOfMemory error at you. Weird. Here is the DateTime field sample, for reference "7/16/2009 9:30:00 AM" (without quotes in the file)

Comment: @Iterator:   $ ProdName      : Factor w/ 1 level "Product1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Date.Time    : Factor w/ 98484 levels "1/11/2010 1:00:00 PM",..: 75451 75452 75453 75454 75455 75456 75457 75458 75459 75460 ...
 $ Price         : num  36.7 36.8 36.8 36.9 36.9 ...

Comment: @Alex K: your 'mydata$Date' is a factor instead of being a date. Conver this column/variable to date (see e.g.: `?as.Date`) and try again.

Comment: @daroczig: I think I have a bigger problem. It looks like as.Date (and I'm assuming Date itself is meant for actual Date and I have Data and Time in one field).

Comment: I should google before I post. I think I found the right function: plot(as.POSIXlt(mydata$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"), mydata$Price). But I swear this is C++ compiler levels of cryptic. OutOfMemory error to this... I never would've made the trip on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the Out Of Memory error has nothing to do with anything apparently. It just that CSV parser does not recognize Date column values as Date and Time combined. Needs extra coercing. Thanks to the suggestions in the replies to my question + google I found the right function for the job. The following code works as I wanted it to:

```
plot(as.POSIXlt(mydata$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"), mydata$Price)
```

I sort of understand that it doesn't really know what I might want from a CSV column, but Out Of Memory error just seems like the exactly the wrong reaction to this.

Comment: it's not a "CSV" column, it's probably a factor and trying to plot a huge histogram based on unique values in Date

Comment: hmm, box and whisker plot that is, not histogram :)

Comment: yep, the Factor thing is what was suggested in the comments for my question too, that's how I was pointed at Date field as the culprit. Problem is that OutOfMemory is the wrong error (since it barely consumes any). At least it should've said which field was causing it. A noob like me is just not equipped to analyze such a situation. A more informative error would've at least lead to me asking a clearer question :)

Comment: The error is issued at the appropriate moment, trying to draw a crazy plot

Comment: The error may be correct, but it carries with it zero information. People guessed at a cause through experience. That's the core issue. This is not something I should've had to come to SO to figure out.